# Add a pop up menu within customui.xml?

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

I am writing a custom menu for Excel by editing `customui.xml`.

The buttons and "dropdown" menus are working fine, but I want to replicate the little arrow in the bottom of the standard Excel and Office menu groups (when you click one of these a whole form pops up). I can do the form, but I can't find in the documentation: how to create that little clickable arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to is called the DialogBoxLauncher, and you can read more about customizing it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb400926(v=office.12).aspx

Also, as an aside, Ron de Bruin maintains what I think is the [ultimate reference](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm) on customizing the Office Ribbon interface.